# Unable to change URL to the root directory of my site in global configuration?

Tags: url, config

Using Expression Engine 2 the going to Admin>General configuration

I am trying to change both "URL to the root directory of your site" and "URL to your "themes" folder"

I can type the changes in no problem but when I come to save it, the setting remains as the original urls

The config file is writable. What else could I be looking at?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Update: Found the solution. I had delete the cache. Not from the CMS but from the actual server folders for cache. Updated no problem